# ¿Cómo llamar una API metodo POST PHP?

Tags: php, json, api

Tengo un problema que espero me puedan apoyar, soy un novato en esto de PHP y deseo usar una API de una empresa que se llama "EnviaYa" para hacer una pagina tipo "tracking" de paquetes.

La idea es que un cliente en un formulario ingrese su número de guia y seleccione la paquetería, el cual tengo de esta forma.

```
<form class="" id="formgenerator"action="tracking.php" method="post">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <table class="table table-dark">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">Numero de guia</th>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="guia" id="guia" placeholder="547412574" required="">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">Paqueteria</th>
                                        <td><select name="paqueteria" class="browser-default custom-select" required="">
                                                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Seleccionar paqueteria</option>
                                                <option value="fedex">FedEx</option>
                                                <option value="dhl">DHL</option>
                                                <option value="99minutos">99Minutos</option>
                                                <option value="ivoy">iVoy</option>
                                                <option value="ups">UPS</option>
                                                <option value="redpack">RedPack</option>
                                            </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rastrear paquete</button>
            
        </div></form>
```

En el archivo track.php solo pude recoger los datos mediante `$_POST` pero ya no se que más hacer, cómo puedo recuperar los datos desde la API y mostrarlos en la misma pantalla o una similar a donde ingresan la guía los usuarios solo tengo esto en PHP

```
<?php
include_once "key.php";
$guia=$_POST["guia"];
$paqueteria=$_POST["paqueteria"];

?>
```

En la documentación me indican este ejemplo:

Example Request

```
POST https://enviaya.com.mx/api/v1/trackings
{
   "carrier_account": null,
   "api_key":"YOUR_API_KEY",
   "carrier":"ups",
   "shipment_number": "1ZA9T9220497543646"
}
```

Y eso devuelve los siguientes valores

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "enviaya_shipment_number": "LE8HZKIW",
    "carrier_tracking_number": "1ZA9T9220497543646",
    "estimated_delivery_date": "19/12/2017",
    "expected_delivery_date": "28/12/2017",
    "delivery_date": "2017-12-21T02:55:00-06:00",
    "pickup_date": "2017-12-13T07:57:39-06:00",
    "shipment_status": "Entregado",
    "event_code": 155,
    "event_description": "Entregado",
    "event": "Entregado",
    "status_code": 50,
    "sub_event_code": null,
    "sub_event": null,
    "sub_event_description": null
}
```

Trabaje con la API de TMDB en algún momento pensé que sería igual pero me di cuenta que para nada o no supe manejarla.

Como puedo en primer lugar enviar los datos a la API y en segundo recuperar la respuesta y poner los datos en pantalla para el cliente?

Espero me puedan apoyar y no molestar a nadie con mi pregunta que quizá es básica para muchos, pero no se mucho del tema ya que estoy aprendiendo.

Gracias a todos de antemano.

```
    <script>
var urlAll='https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/<?php echo $identificador;?>?api_key=<?php echo $API_KEY_IMDB;?>&language=es-ES&append_to_response=external_ids';
var urlVideo='https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/<?php echo $identificador;?>/videos?api_key=<?php echo $API_KEY_IMDB;?>&language=EN-US';
$.ajax({
        url:urlVideo ,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'video'
      }).error(function() {
        console.log('error')
      }).done(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          var trailer=response.results[0].key;
          document.getElementById("trailer").value=trailer;
    });
$.ajax({
        url:urlAll ,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback: 'testing'
      }).error(function() {
        console.log('error')
      }).done(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=response.name+" ("+response.first_air_date.substr(0,4)+") ";
        document.getElementById("datos-principales").style.backgroundImage="url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"+response.backdrop_path+")";
        document.getElementById("posterHref").href="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"+response.poster_path;
        document.getElementById("poster").src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"+response.poster_path;
        var generos="";
        for(var i = 0; i < response.genres.length; i++) 
        {    
            if(i==0){
            var generos=generos+response.genres[i].name;       
            }else{
                var generos=generos+" , "+response.genres[i].name;       
            }
        }
        var creadores="";
        for(var i = 0; i < response.created_by.length; i++) 
        {    
            
            if(i==0){
            var creadores=creadores+response.created_by[i].name;       
            }else{
                var creadores=creadores+" , "+response.created_by[i].name;       
            } 

        }
        
 var trailerlabel=document.getElementById("trailer").value;
        
var consultahtml='  &lt;div class="sinopsis5"&gt; '+response.overview+'&lt;/div&gt;<br><br>                        &lt;div class="detalles5"&gt;<br>      TItulo Original: &lt;b&gt;'+response.original_name+'&lt;/b&gt;<br>                                             Año: &lt;b&gt;'+response.first_air_date.substr(0,4)+'&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Pais(es): &lt;b&gt;'+response.production_countries[0].name+', &lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Creador(es): &lt;b&gt; '+creadores + '&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Duración: &lt;b&gt;'+response.episode_run_time[0]+' min.&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Genero: &lt;b&gt;'+generos+' &lt;/b&gt;<br>                        &lt;a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/'+response.external_ids.imdb_id+'" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://bit.ly/imdbicon" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;<br>                        &lt;/div&gt;<br><br>                        &lt;div class="capturas5"&gt;<br>                        &lt;img src="<?php echo $capturaUno;?>" /&gt;<br>                       &lt;img src="<?php echo $capturaDos;?>" /&gt;<br>      &lt;img src="<?php echo $capturaTres;?>" /&gt;<br>                 &lt;img src="<?php echo $capturaCuatro;?>" /&gt;<br>         &lt;img src="<?php echo $capturaCinco;?>" /&gt;<br>                                                                                     &lt;/div&gt;<br><br>                        &lt;div class="trailer5"&gt;<br>                        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+trailerlabel+'<br>                        &lt;/div&gt;<br><br>                                                &lt;div class="descarga6"&gt;<br>                        Audio: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $audio;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Calidad: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $calidad;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Resolución: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $resolucion;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Formato: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $formato;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Tamaño: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $tamano;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Codec: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $codec;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Subtítulos: &lt;b&gt;<?php echo $subs;?>&lt;/b&gt;<br>                        Servidores: &lt;img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive"&gt; &lt;img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=uptobox.com"&gt;<br>                        Subido por: &lt;a href="https://www.<?php echo $siteUploader;?>" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"&gt;&lt;b style="color:yellow"&gt;<?php echo $uploader;?>&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/a&gt;<br>                        <br>                        &lt;a class="link5free" style="color: #20b8f8;" href="<?php echo $linkfree;?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;ENLACES PÚBLICOS&lt;/a&gt;<br>                        &lt;a class="link5vip" style="color: #cba901;" href="<?php echo $linkvip;?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;ENLACES VIP&lt;/a&gt;<br>                        &lt;/div&gt;<br><br>                    &lt;div class="final5"&gt;Si eres de esas personas que te molesta pasar por los acortadores puedes pasarte a VIP.<br>                        &lt;a class="link5vip" style="color: #cba901;" href="https://bit.ly/2OAVQzR"&gt;OBTENER AQUI&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;<br>';
document.getElementById("codigo").innerHTML=consultahtml;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: El título dice `get` pero en la pregunta mencionas `post`. No quieres usar `post`?

Comment: @Bicho una disculpa me lie con los términos ya lo corregi, si la API dice que se pasan los datos por POST

Comment: Tienes que crear un código para hacer la petición a la API, puede que cURL sea una buena opción para este caso. Sea como sea, ¿qué has investigado, qué has intentado y qué problema o error tienes?

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahorita use un software que se llama "Postman" para ver como es la solicitud a la URL de la API porque la verdad ni eso sabia hacer.

He visto que es muy similar a la API de TMDB, solo que no se como adaptar el codigo ya que ese en particular crea una salida con un "codigo HTML" previamente definido pero no se como hacerle para que solo muestre los estatus. Tengo el código al final de la pregunta como podría adaptarlo si es posible.

Comment: Hay muchas cosas que aún no quedan claras en tu pregunta. Tú puedes consultar a la API usando código cliente (Javascript) con una petición parecida a lo que tienes con Ajax (una desventaja de hacer esto es que si usas una clave de API esta quedaría expuesta  y otros podrían hacer uso de ella, a no ser que la misma API te dé posibilidad de autorizar peticiones por nombre de dominio). O puedes consultarla usando código de servidor (PHP) en cuyo caso te recomendaría usar cURL. En cualquiera de los casos tienes que informarte con tu API lo que ellos requieren para ...

Comment: ... autorizar las peticiones. O sea, cómo deben ir las cabeceras, si se debe incluir una API KEY, etc, etc. Con esa información armarías la petición, decidiendo de qué lado quieres hacerlo, si del lado del cliente (con Ajax/Javascript o con Fetch/Javascript)  o del lado del servidor (con cURL/PHP o de otro modo).